# Skips over system out, scan nextLine, and if loops

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

New here (and to Java!).  I've searched around the site for an answer to my problem but came up naught.  This program executes up to the `scan.nextDouble` statement.

If I enter a salary value such as "8," I get:

```
/////OUTPUT/////  
Enter the performance rating (Excellent, Good, or Poor):  
Current Salary:       $8.00  
Amount of your raise: $0.00  
Your new salary:      $8.00  
/////END OF OUTPUT/////
```

So obviously, my following scan.nextLine and all the if-else statements are bypassed.  What am I missing?

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class Salary 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        double currentSalary;  // employee's current  salary
        double raise = 0;          // amount of the raise
        double newSalary = 0;      // new salary for the employee
        String rating;         // performance rating
        String rating1 = new String("Excellent");
        String rating2 = new String("Good");
        String rating3 = new String("Poor");

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print ("Enter the current salary: ");
        currentSalary = scan.nextDouble();
        System.out.print ("Enter the performance rating (Excellent, Good, or Poor): ");
        rating = scan.nextLine();

        // Compute the raise using if ...
        if (rating.equals(rating1))

            raise = .06;

        else

        if (rating.equals(rating2))

            raise = .04;

        else

        if (rating.equals(rating3))

            raise = .015;

        else

            newSalary = currentSalary + currentSalary * raise;

         // Print the results
        {
        NumberFormat money = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Current Salary:       " + money.format(currentSalary));
        System.out.println("Amount of your raise: " + money.format(raise));
        System.out.println("Your new salary:      " + money.format(newSalary));
        System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest adding braces (`{}`) to the if-statements. Now only in the case where it doesn't match any of the words given (either 'excellent', 'good' or 'poor') the new salary will be calculated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you scan input using scanner.nextDouble() it takes only the float value and leaves the new line character in the buffer so after that when you do scanner.nextLine(() it takes the new line character and returns empty string.Put another scanner.nextLine() before scanning the next line to eat up the new line character

```
currentSalary = scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.print ("Enter the performance rating (Excellent, Good, or Poor): ");
    scan.nextLine(); 
    rating = scan.nextLine();
```

Comment: That did the trick.  Thx!  I was able to t-shoot the rest of the program once I got that working.

Comment: @slaverock68 good that it works.dont forget to accept the answer so that people know this problem is solved also please do upvote my answer

Answer (score 0):

Scanner.nextDouble() just reads the next available double value and does not by itself point to next line.

use a dummy scanner.nextLine() before your actual one. that lets your cursor point to next line from which your scanner.nextline() takes the input.

-cheers :)

Comment: And thank you as well for your input.  Same as above ^.  Semper Fi